# Chanuka Candle Location

Tags: chanuka, travel, candle-lighting

My whole family will be staying at a hotel over shabbos and the hotel management says that we are not allowed to light fires in our rooms.  Nobody will be in our home.  How can we fulfill the mitzvah of chanuka candles?

Comment: Isn't this a halachik question? Isn't it better if you ask your Rav?

Comment: Anyone who faces this question for real should consult their Rabbi when determining what to do. However, it could still be useful to talk to friends (or yodeyans, in this case) first to see what practical options may be available, and worth evaluating with the Rabbi. Also, the question is worth discussing purely for the Torah learning value. See also: http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/01/more-from-linkedin-what-if-crowd-is.html

Answer (score 3):

[R' Eylashiv](http://www.localjewishnews.com/2010/11/30/important-halachos-for-hanukah-from-harav-eliyashiv-shlita/) that in such a situation one shouldn't light, and if one did, he wouldn't be yotzei. Therefore, he advises people not to stay in such a place over Chanuka.

[If one cannot light](http://www.torah.org/learning/integrity/menorah_brachos.html), then if one could see someone elses' lit candle, say "She'asah Nissim" and "Shehechiyanu".

If one is far from any Jews and can't see any candle, one shouldn't make any blessing as it's a sofek brochos lehakel (any blessing over which there is a doubt one doesn't say).

Answer (score 2):

Did you ask the hotel management if there's some other place where you could light? My understanding is that second choice after wherever you're sleeping is wherever you're eating. Perhaps you could find a place (maybe even outside) where you could light your menora and monitor it while you eat your dinner.

Another possibility: Get yourself invited to someone's home for dinner, and light there.

I'm not 100% sure about the Halachic rules regarding lighting where you're going to eat but not sleep, so I'd recommend checking with your Rabbi before implementing these.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of people stuck in a hotel where the rabbi told them to just not light.

Comment: When we were in a hospital over shabbos, we were able to use an electric menorah with incandescent bulbs (not fluorescent) with a bracha. See http://dinonline.org/2014/11/06/electric-lights-for-shabbos-candles/

Answer (score 0):

There are many Yeshivas that also do not allow lighting in the rooms due to Sakana. Maybe the hotel management would allow lighting if you remain with them or designate a safe area where they would allow it. Alternatively you can purchase an electric Menorah and use that B'Shaas Hadchak.